# PHP - Output array, Convert to links, String Replace

Tags: php, arrays, replace, explode

I have an array full of names like this in a database entry:

```
Bob Smith, Bob Smith, Bob Smith, Bob Smith
```

I need to output the array to where each name becomes an individual link like so:

```
<a href="bob-smith.php">Bob Smith</a>, <a href="bob-smith.php">Bob Smith</a>, <a href="bob-smith.php">Bob Smith</a>, <a href="bob-smith.php">Bob Smith</a>
```

So I need to create these links solely from the names in that database entry. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, it sounds like a simple while / foreach loop.

Comment: That won't distinguish between "Bob Smith" and "Bob-Smith". There could occur names where it does make a difference. Consider also `urlencode` and/or an underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this.

```
$name = 'Bob Smith, Bob Smith, Bob Smith, Bob Smith';

$arr = explode(", ", $name);

$out = array();
foreach($arr as $value){
    $link = strtolower(implode("-", explode(" ", $value)));
    $out[] = '<a href="'.$link.'.php">'.$value.'</a>';
}
$str = implode(", ", $out);
```

If now we echo the `$str` then the output is with link. Not viewable the tags. SO use `htmlspecialchars`.

**Result**

```
echo htmlspecialchars($str); // <a href="bob-smith.php">Bob Smith</a>, <a href="bob-smith.php">Bob Smith</a>, <a href="bob-smith.php">Bob Smith</a>, <a href="bob-smith.php">Bob Smith</a>
```

Comment: This was the first working answer that also included the commas in the output. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in simple way like:

```
<?php
    $as = array('Bob Smith', 'Bob Smith', 'Bob Smith', 'Bob Smith');
    $s = "";
    foreach ($as as $a)
        $s .= '<a href="', str_replace(" ", "-", strtolower($a)), '.php">', $a, '</a>, ';
    echo trim($s, ", ");
?>
```

**Updated** with the trimming of the trailing comma. I would suggest that the best way would be using arrays and `implode`ing them.

```
<?php
    $as = array('Bob Smith', 'Bob Smith', 'Bob Smith', 'Bob Smith');
    $s = array();
    foreach ($as as $a)
        $s[] = '<a href="', str_replace(" ", "-", strtolower($a)), '.php">', $a, '</a>, ';
    echo implode(", ", $s);
?>
```

Comment: actually you have a comma too much after the last link ;P

Comment: @Poiz Na, you screwed it up. I changed the logic totally.

Comment: well any of our answers will help him ^^

Comment: As it is now, it overwrites `$s` in each loop and echoes the last one. Possibly you wanted to `$s .= `.

Comment: Excuse me... not intentionally... but would you be kind enough to point out where?

Comment: @Poiz I know your intentions were good. Don't worry. :) Not blaming you sorry. `:P` Man, don't take it in a wrong sense.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$names = array('Bob Smith', 'John Doe');
foreach ($names as $name) {

    echo '<a href="'. str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($name)) .'.php">'. $name . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Actually, that's not the same as what OP wants. `;P`

Answer (score 1):

You may use either an obvious foreach or array_map:

```
<?php
$names = ['Bob Smith', 'Bob Smith', 'Bob Smith', 'Bob Smith'];
$links = array_map(function($name) {
    $url = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $name)) . '.php';
    return '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a>';
}, $names);
echo implode('<br/>', $links);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple foreach:

```
$names = array('Steve Waugh', 'Mark Waugh', 'Adam Gilchrist');
$links = array();
if (! empty($names)) {
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        $urlTo = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $name)) . '.php';
        $links[] = '<a href="'.$urlTo.'">' . $name . '</a>';
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($links);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a href="steve-waugh.php">Steve Waugh</a>
    [1] => <a href="mark-waugh.php">Mark Waugh</a>
    [2] => <a href="adam-gilchrist.php">Adam Gilchrist</a>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$names = array('Bob Smith', 'John Smith');
foreach ($names as $name) {
  echo preg_replace(array("#[\s-]+#"), array("-"), trim(strtolower($name))).'.php';
}
?>
```

Comment: Rather than just pasting a random bunch of code, explain what you did and why. That way, the OP and any future readers with the same problem can actually learn something from your answer, rather than just copy/pasting it and asking the same question again tomorrow.